# Как настроить dnsmasq только под прокси DNS?

Tags: centos, dns

Есть файрволл на CentOS, внезапно на нем сломался проброс порта 53/udp на DNS-сервер (отдельная тема), причем так, что пакеты, адресованные на внешний интерфейс, стали проваливаться в INPUT. Побороть не сумел, детали борьбы тут  https://serverfault.com/questions/926165/iptables-stopped-translating-dns-packets поэтому ищу обходной вариант - настроить типа-прокси для внезапно недоступного сервера. Смотрю на dnsmasq, он вроде умеет, но опций как-то много, а это продакшн и нельзя ошибиться, иначе можно получить рекурсию и проблемы у всех сразу. Какие опции помимо сервера, куда ломиться, нужно указать этому dnsmasq, чтобы он ничего больше не пытался делать?

Comment: [Dnsmasq accepts DNS queries and either answers them from a small, local, cache or forwards them to a real, recursive, DNS server.](http://www.thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/docs/dnsmasq-man.html) — это поведение **по умолчанию**.

Comment: То есть просто никаких. Он даже авторитативный ответ отдает, если сервер главный для этого домена.